# Reset huawei Ascend P7

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, factory-reset, huawei, huawei-ascend-p7

I'm trying to reset my phone, but It doesn't work. When I try to reset it via android settings, it restarts, shows the Huawei logo and shutsdown. When I manually restart it its back to its original state before the backup.

I cant boot into recovery or fastboot, it justs shows a black screen. My phone is rooted, but I don't have root acces because of immutable.list. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: How were you trying to get into recovery/fastboot? Did you flash a custom recovery?

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have this device, I can't say too much. Also, I can't comment because of my rep. But whatever.

Try to flash recovery even if your flashboot returns blank screen. It might not work, but hey! give it a try!

Also, try to look [Here](http://firmwarefile.com/huawei-ascend-p7-l10) or [Here](http://www.mobileflashtool.com/2015/12/huawei-ascend-p7-flash-file-firmware-download.html), it says about flashing firmware.

Answer (score -2):

Shutdown your Phone and then press and hold Volume down + Power.
Normally should your Phone reset then.
If this doesn't work, you may have destroyed the recovery.

Comment: As I said, I **cant** boot into recovery.

Comment: Is there a recovery tool from huawei?

Comment: Yes Hi-Suite, but I says that my phone is healthy.

Comment: Can you reset or reflash in this tool?

Comment: Yes, but it says that my phone is healthy.

Comment: What does healthy has to do with recovering a phone?

Comment: Well, since it think that my phone is healthy it doesn't let me recover.

Comment: Ok... That is Huawei... Doesn't make any sense